# Parse JSON response in Android to access multidimensional array

Tags: android, json

My json output is as follows:

http://tinyurl.com/qceyd2z

How to parse it in Android?

I have been using iteration to loop over object collection1 without success.
I want to access my array collection1 under object result:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

        // Getting JSON Array node
        contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString(string1);
            String name = c.getString(string2);
            String email = c.getString(string3);
            String address = c.getString(string4);
            String gender = c.getString(string5);
            ...
```

Comment: Try to include more code, i.e. how do you get the ``jsonStr`` and at least complete the code snippet you included.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
  try {
       JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

       JSONObject jsonResult=jsonObj.getJSONObject("results");
   JSONArray jsonArrayCollection=jsonResult.getJSONArray("collection1");

       // looping through All Collection
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayCollection.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject collctns = jsonArrayCollection.getJSONObject(i);
             String prop1Href=collctns.getJSONObject("property1").getString("href");
             String prop1Text=collctns.getJSONObject("property1").getString("text");
             String prop2=collctns..getString("property2")
      } 
  }catch(JSONException e){
     e.printStaceTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Libraries Like `GSON` That will save u lot of time in parsing JSON data... here is a sample tutorial to get started..

Tutorial : [link](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON)